# Azure Data Factory - REST API duplicates when using request_header pagination rule

Tags: azure, rest, pagination, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to pull data from REST API using ADF's bulit-in connector.
In the API response header I have 'Link' value to the next page:

[image]

**But when using pagination rules for REST API connector like this:**
[image]

**It imports the same pages over and over again and causes obvious duplicates and redundant API calls.**

I tried different combinations of name/value rules:

- *Headers['Link']: Headers.Link* (casues same as above)
- *Headers.Link: Headers['Link']* (casues same as above)
- *AbsoluteUrl: Headers['Link']* (causes 404)

Any Idea how to solve this?

Thanks!